# Vaadin 8 grid: Size image in grid cell?

Tags: vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I try to render an image in a grid cell as follows:

```
grid.addColumn(probe ->
    new ThemeResource("img/" + probe.getStructureData().getImageFileName()),
    new ImageRenderer()
).setCaption("Structure");
```

I want to set the size of the image in pixel. How can I do this? It seems the ImageRenderer has no method for this. 
Of cause I could size my images before. But I would like to add a big image that should be shown as tooltip and a small version of the same image should be shown in the grid cell. I would like to avoid adding the same image in 2 sizes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it this way.

```
grid.addComponentColumn(probe -> {
    Image image = new Image("", new ThemeResource("img/" + probe.getStructureData().getImageFileName()));
    image.setWidth(100, Sizeable.Unit.PIXELS);
    image.setHeight(100, Sizeable.Unit.PIXELS);

    return image;
}).setCaption("Structure");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This does work well. I only had to remove "Sizeable". Maybe you are using a different Vaadin version.

Comment: My Unit class is in _com.vaadin.server.Sizeable_. You can also use `image.setHeight("100px");`